# can't we store char values inside integer variable

Tags: c++

I was trying to store character value inside integer variable but it throws error. So I have highlighted the problem with the following code:

```
# include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int userInput;
    char character = 'a';

    cout<<"Enter a value in the prompt ";
    cin>>userInput;
    cout<<userInput<<endl;
    if(userInput == 'a' ){
        cout<<"True";

    }
    else{
        cout<<"Match failed";
    }
return 0;   
}

Output:
Enter a value in the prompt a
0
Match Failed
```

So I dont understand why is it happening? It also prints the value 0 after taking the input 'a'from the user. So does it never save the charater value

Comment: C++ streams are type safe.  They won't allow you to enter a character (there are some exceptions) into a variable the expects a number.

Comment: Why you want to save character value in integer variable?

Comment: `a` in particular *will* work if you read the integer as hex: `cin >> hex >> userInput;` and result in the value 10. By default it only accepts decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `operator>>` to input an integer, the `operator>>` is looking for the characters, '0'...'9' (digits for a number).  It will collect the digits, then create a number.

When you use `operator>>` to input a *character*, the `operator>>` will read one character and store into the variable.

You can convert a *character* to its number by using an *encoding*, such as ASCII.